Could another star render color better than the Sun? If so, would a human be able to tell?
Disclaimer: This might be a better question for Worldbuilding SE, not completely sure.
I read today that the standard method of measuring color rendering index (CRI) is based on natural light (e.g. from the Sun) and that the CRI of any light source is limited to 100, which is the CRI of the Sun. It's my understanding however that the Sun's spectrum is not exactly that of an idealized black body, and so it still doesn't render color perfectly (if such a thing is possible). From this I gather that theoretically, a source of light could exist that renders color better than natural daylight on Earth.
That isn't my question, though. What I really want to know is whether a star could exist in reality that renders color better than our Sun, what class/composition would be necessary, and so on. Would it be appropriate to give this star a CRI greater than 100? (101? 102? 100.009?)
I would also like to know if a human could tell visually that this star renders color better than our sun, or if our eyes only have the capacity to match our star's spectrum.

Sunlight is very close to a black body spectrum. I doubt human eyes have the sensitivity to tell the difference.

What do you mean by "renders colour" and how would we measure that as physicists?

The human visual perception system performs extensive processing. Among the features achieved by that processing is color constancy
Color constancy is that the visual system is still able to suss out what the color properties of a particular surface are, even when the illumination is significantly different from average daylight.
That is, the human visual system assigns color, and that process of assigning color is tuned to average daylight, but there is also extensive capability to compensate for a range of deviation from average.

Summarizing:
For color recognition the exact composition of the illuminating light source is not a particularly significant factor.
Color assignment happens mainly at a neuronal processing level; the responses of the photo-receptive cells in the retina are an intermediate stage.


That said: for high performance color calibration the illumination source is standardized to a high level of specification.
The purpose of the standardization is to make the calibration process highly reproducible. Daylight spectrum is not a single thing, it's different depending on place and time of day. For the purpose of reproducibility a standardized illumination is a specific spectral composition.

The spectrum of the light source does matter. You can see this with lights of different color temperature. Lower color temperatures emphasize the warmer, redder colors. Higher color temperatures emphasize the colder, bluer colors.
A star that does better than the Sun? It would depend on what you mean my better. A hotter star would be brighter and bluer. A red dwarf would be dimmer and redder. You could adjust the distance to the star to get the same apparent brightness. But the colors would be different.
Color rendering index is a measure of how closely an illuminant makes the color appearance match that from natural daylight. So any different from the "perfect" illuminant would distort the colors and get a worse than $100$ rating.

We evolved under the light of our sun, so also our color perception.
